# How to import a function and apply to this within vue app

Tags: typescript, vue.js

Is there a way in Typescript and Vue (v2.x) to import a function that references `this`?

I haven't had luck with `mixins`, and curious if there's a simple approach here.

For example:

**getPath.ts**

```js
export default getPath(): string {
    return this.$route.path; // 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)
}
```

**App.vue**

```js
import getPath from "./getPath";
import Vue from "vue";
export default Vue.extend({
    mounted(){
       const path = getPath().apply(this);
    }
});
```

I'm getting the error:

> 'this' implicitly has type 'any' because it does not have a type annotation.ts(2683)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
import { Route } from 'vue-router';
declare module "vue/types/vue" { // extend vue typings 
  interface Vue {
    $route: Route;
  }
}
```

```
// specify `this` context
export function getPath(this: Vue, ...args: any[]): string {
  return this.$route.path; 
}
```

```
mounted(){
  const path = this.getPath(1,2,3);
},
methods: {
  getPath,
}
```

Comment: Thanks @ABOS, how would i apply this pattern if `getPath(arg)` had an existing argument?

Comment: @d-_-b, I updated answer. does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use composition api `useRoutePath.ts`:

```
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
export default useRoutePath () {
    const route = userRoute();
    const getPath = () => route.path;
    return {
      getPath,
    }
}
```

It already has types and can be extended any time (like get params id or meta)